# siunitx's S column misaligns numbers if retain-unity-mantissa is false

Tags: tables, siunitx

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l @{\hskip+0.5em} S[retain-unity-mantissa = false]}
    \toprule
    Force           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Relative Strength} \\
    \midrule
    Strong          & 1                                     \\
    Electromagnetic & 1e-3                                  \\
    Weak            & 1e-8                                  \\
    Gravity         & 1e-37                                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image: Bad Result]

Clearly the numbers are not aligned properly. Am I using `siunitx` improperly or is this a bug? If so, can someone think of a fix / workaround?

Comment: This case is quite difficult to handle. You could help us by telling us, what you would like to obtain here. `1` aligned over `0` or `10^0`? What about the case, where the second line reads `2e-3`? You can make your wishes and I guess we will find a solution but the best case would be some general rule for this case (and even better some standard or reference...)

Comment: Well, I'd expect that the start of all numbers line up vertically, i.e. the `1` should be aligned over the `1` of `10^-3`. Consequentially, for the number `2e-3` the `2` should line up with the `1`.

Comment: Your first case: normally, we would align 1 over 0 here, just try a table (1, 10, 100). Why do you want to align tens and units? Your second case: Have you tried that? `2e-3` prints as `2 x 10^-3` so this is really a different thing.

Comment: In my case, the powers of tens are not units. The table is supposed to show that the forces act with at vastly different strength. Hence I consider both `1` and `10^-3` as a number and would like them to line up accordingly.

Comment: This misalignment here is a bug, but to be honest it's not a case I'd considered: the `S` column is really about aligning decimals. I'll post an answer avoiding using `siunitx` at all, at least for the moment.

Comment: 1 and 1e-3 should be presented with the same representation. Because 10^-3 is a shorthand and it should also apply to 1 too. Otherwise you are mixing representations. Relative representations expect mantissa and adjust the exponents accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This is really on the edge of the scope for `siunitx` (as there is no decimal part). Certainly the issue should be addressed but for the moment a low-level solution might be best. For example, if we can assume that we can grab the cell content by picking up the `\\` delimiter then something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newlength\mylength
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth\mylength{$10^{-37}$}}
\newcommand*\autoexp{}
\def\autoexp\ignorespaces#1\\{\autoexpaux#1e\stop\\}
\newcommand\autoexpaux{}
\def\autoexpaux#1e#2\stop{%
  \setbox0=\hbox to \mylength{%
    $
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
      #1
    \else
      \ifnum#1=1 %
      \else
        \times
      \fi
      \autoexpauxii#2\stop
    \fi
    $%
    \hfil
  }%
  \hfil\box0\hfil
}
\newcommand\autoexpauxii{}
\def\autoexpauxii#1e#2\stop{10^{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l>{\autoexp}l@{}}
    \toprule
    Force           & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Relative Strength\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}} \\
    \midrule
    Strong          & 1                                     \\
    Electromagnetic & 1e-3                                  \\
    Weak            & 1e-8                                  \\
    Gravity         & 1e-37                                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

will work. The idea here is to grab the cell content and then do a quick parse: if there is a `e` part, use that but drop any leading `1`, if there is no `e` use it directly. Everything is boxed up into a width equal to the (hard-coded) widest column, then that box is placed correctly  under the heading.

Refinements are possible, for example collecting the cells more robustly, allowing for different forms of numbers, *etc.*, but that is probably best done by me fixing `siunitx` here.

Answer (score 3):

This case it not treated in the `siunitx` package, as it is quite difficult to say, what should happen. If you are aligning numbers, you should align units over units, tens over tens, hundreds over hundreds... For exponential notation, this gets more complicated as you are mixing powers with normal numbers. I guess, the best solution would be to write `10^0` for the first line as this would look most consistent. In every case, you will have to type that manually.

Here is your version with `1` in the second row (not left aligned like in your comment, as this looks really confusing):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l @{\hskip+0.5em} S[table-format = 2.0, table-space-text-post =\textsuperscript{$-37$}]}
        \toprule
        Force           & {Relative Strength}       \\
        \midrule
        Strong          & 1                         \\
        Electromagnetic & 10\textsuperscript{$-3$}  \\
        Weak            & 10\textsuperscript{$-8$}  \\
        Gravity         & 10\textsuperscript{$-37$} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]